# How to organize libs with Python + Google App Engine + oauthlib

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My problem is following error:

```
ImportError: No module named oauthlib.oauth2
```

So as it appears I can't import [oauthlib](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib) in gae dev environemnt

I have following project structure

```
app_root/
    app/          - source files of the app
    libs/         - third party libraries
      gdata/      - google data library
      atom/       - requires by google data
      oauthlib/   - [oauthlib][1]
    test/         - unit tests
app.yaml          - gae config
main.py           - main script
```

Here is the source of the app.yaml

```
application: app
version: v1

runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

In main.py I have following code to pick up on 'libs' folder:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'libs'))
```

and finally I have following import in my module:

```
from oauthlib.oauth2 import RequestValidator, WebApplicationServer
```

as result when I start application from [pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) I get this error:

```
    from oauthlib.oauth2 import RequestValidator, WebApplicationServer
ImportError: No module named oauthlib.oauth2
```

I really do not understand why it happens, in my IDE it doesn't highlight that import as red, so it can see that reference is good.

I am kinda new to python and all this approach with third-party libraries really confuses me. In fact there a lot of questions about this, like is there a better way to manage third-party libraries for gae.

But lets focus on the main issue. Why it throws ImportError when reference should be fine?

**UPDATE #1**
If I make libs as a python package, so there **init**.py 
It breaks imports inside library code, i.e. file oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py contains:

```
from oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749 import tokens
from oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.parameters import prepare_token_request
from oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors import TokenExpiredError
from oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors import InsecureTransportError
from oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.utils import is_secure_transport
```

But current module path includes libs.prefix

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you should be able to do this with a simple `__init__.py` placed in the right place in the path:

```
app_root/
    app/          - source files of the app
    libs/         - third party libraries
      __init__.py - # Add this
      gdata/      - google data library
      atom/       - requires by google data
      oauthlib/   - [oauthlib][1]
    test/         - unit tests
app.yaml          - gae config
main.py           - main script
```

Now, rather than messing with `sys.path`, you can do something like:

```
from libs.oauthlib.oauth2 import RequestValidator, WebApplicationServer
```

---

If you *really* want to keep playing with your system's path, then I *think* you need another `os.path.dirname` in there since your `.py` files seem to be in `app`.  As it is, you seem to be looking for `lib` in the same directory as the python source files.:

```
app_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
root_dir = os.path.dirname(app_dir)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(root_dir, 'libs'))
```

Comment: notice that main.py (where I extend system path) located on the same level as lib folder so I do not look for the lib folder inside of the app folder, as for your first suggestion I updated my question